# Power Spectral Density and Total Power Calculation for Signal

Tags: python, matlab, signals, signal-processing, communication

I am currently working on analyzing a signal with the autocorrelation function given by:

R(τ) = 100 * cos( 10000 * τ*pi) .* (Λ(2000τ))^2

I need assistance in plotting the power spectral density *Gf*​(*ω*) of this signal. Additionally, I am interested in calculating the total power of the signal and specifically determining its power within the frequency range of 10kHz≤∣*ω*∣≤12kHz.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to approach this problem or share some code snippets in MATLAB/Python that could help me achieve these objectives?

Thank you in advance for your support!

I have attempted to implement the calculation of the power spectral density and total power using the given autocorrelation function in MATLAB/Python. Specifically, I've looked into functions like **`fft`**, **`pwelch`**, and related signal processing tools.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.